# change timestamp in multiple columns to proper date (e.g YYYYMMDD)

Tags: bash, date, awk, sed, timestamp

I have the following file:

```
91001440737;1421687191;1421687966;10;true;true;1421816564;;;;;;;;;
91001477235;1422551333;;3;true;true;;;;;;1422789053;;;1422789053;
91001512152;;1423070412;2;true;true;;;;;;1423134381;;;;
91001520460;1421600655;;13;true;true;1421665705;;;;1422443201;;;;;
91001627323;1422724554;;10;true;true;1422939818;;;;;;;;;
91001680088;1421535875;;2;true;true;;;1422680695;;;1421579247;;;;
```

Some of the columns (like the 2nd and the 3rd one and others) have timestamps. I would like to change them into proper date.

I have used the following command line to do so:

```
cat fic_v1_entier.txt | while read line ; do echo $line\;$(date +%Y/%m/%d) ; done
```

But the command line is not correct as it gives me this result instead:

```
91001680088;1421535875;;2;true;true;;;1422680695;;;1421579247;;;;;2015/02/18
```

As you can see only the last column have been changed when I want the 2nd , the 3rd and also other specific columns to be changed.

Any tips are welcomed.

Comment: How can you expect the command working??

Comment: Hi @hek2mgl, I expect the command will change the column I'm indicating will be transformed to date.

Comment: I mean, you presented an example that shows "what you have tried".. how do you expect that working - even a bit?

Comment: @hek2mgl, the read line should check all the occurence with timestamp. Am I correct?

Comment: What format is the timestamp in? Is it epoch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this can be done easily using awk

```
awk -F\; 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}
         { $2 = strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$2)
           $3 = strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$3)}1'
```

**Test**

*Here only the second and third (`$2` and `$3`) are changed.*

```
$ awk -F\; 'BEGIN {OFS=";"} { $2 = strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$2); $3 = strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$3)}1'

91001440737;2015/01/19;2015/01/19;10;true;true;1421816564;;;;;;;;;
91001477235;2015/01/29;1970/01/01;3;true;true;;;;;;1422789053;;;1422789053;
91001512152;1970/01/01;2015/02/04;2;true;true;;;;;;1423134381;;;;
91001520460;2015/01/18;1970/01/01;13;true;true;1421665705;;;;1422443201;;;;;
91001627323;2015/01/31;1970/01/01;10;true;true;1422939818;;;;;;;;;
91001680088;2015/01/18;1970/01/01;2;true;true;;;1422680695;;;1421579247;;;;
```

Comment: note you have to use the timestamp given by the 2nd / 3rd column, not the one from your system. `$2 =  strftime("%Y/%m/%d", $2)` should make it.

Comment: @fedorqui But in the sample output the date in the last column is the current date `2015/02/18`. Am not sure if thats what OP wants

Comment: This is happening because the OP says `echo $line\;$(date +%Y/%m/%d)`, which is incorrect. I based my answer in the sentence "Some of the columns (like the 2nd and the 3rd one and others) have timestamps. I would like to change them into proper date."

Comment: Hi @nu11p01n73R, as @fedorqui pointed out, I need to use the timestamp within the file. 

By using your example, I have this `awk -F\; ' {OFS=";"}  { $2 = strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$2)}1 { $3 = strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$3)}1' input` . It is working well.

Comment: @AndyK you could even say `awk -F\; ' BEGIN{OFS=";"; split("1 2 ...", a);} { for (i in a) $i = strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$i)}1' file`, so that you define in the "split" function the fields you want to update.

Comment: @AndyK I missunderstood the question. Glad to help

Comment: @fedorqui use `$a[i]` or you would just be using  1 to however many elements in the array

Comment: @JID errr... you are right! I did a test in which I used 1 2 3 so I couldn't see the difference :)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R `1 { $3 = strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$3)}` the one here is not needed as it is evaluating to true everytime and then executing the block. The block is executed by default anyway.Guessing it was just a typo though anyway

Comment: @JID It was indeed a typo

Comment: I have fixed the code again to avoid setting `OFS` in every line. By saying `BEGIN {OFS="..."}` it just happens before processing the file, which is better.

Answer (score 3):

You can for example say:

```
while IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 f3
do
    printf "%s;%s;%s\n" "$f1" $([ -n "$f2" ] && date -d@"$f2" "+%F%T" || echo "") "$f3"
done < file
```

That is, read every field and apply `date` to the required ones. To do the same with the rest of the variables you need to say `read -r f1 f2 f3 ... fN` and apply the same logic.

Note I used the `%F%T` format, whereas you can say `%Y%m%d` or whatever you prefer. And to do the conversion I use the expression `date -d@timestamp "+format"`.

Also note you are saying `cat file | while ...`, whereas `while ... < file` is more than enough and even better: [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

#### Test

```
$ while IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 f3; do printf "%s;%s;%s\n" "$f1" $([ -n "$f2" ] && date -d@"$f2" "+%F%T" || echo "") "$f3"; done < file
91001440737;2015-01-1918:06:31;1421687966;10;true;true;1421816564;;;;;;;;;
91001477235;2015-01-2918:08:53;;3;true;true;;;;;;1422789053;;;1422789053;
91001512152;1423070412;2;true;true;;;;;;1423134381;;;;;
91001520460;2015-01-1818:04:15;;13;true;true;1421665705;;;;1422443201;;;;;
91001627323;2015-01-3118:15:54;;10;true;true;1422939818;;;;;;;;;
91001680088;2015-01-1800:04:35;;2;true;true;;;1422680695;;;1421579247;;;;
```

Comment: Shouldn't all timestamps being replaced by the date?

Comment: True, only that the OP mentions that it can be the 2nd, 3rd and others, so I am showing how to do it for one. Doing it for the rest is just a matter of extrapolating the method :)

Comment: Really nice one, added something that was missing in OP's question +1

Comment: you should always quote your variables (e.g. `"$f1"`, not `$f1`) unless you have a very specific purpose in mind by not quoting them and fully understand all the implications and caveats. As written it'd pull in the names of all files in the working directory if the first field in the input file was `*`, for example.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I keep forgeting it. No excuses. Just updated, thanks @EdMorton !

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for string functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=";"
    split("2 3 7 9 11 12 15",tsFlds,/ /)
}
{
    for (i=1; i in tsFlds; i++) {
        if ($(tsFlds[i]) != "") {
            $(tsFlds[i]) = strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$(tsFlds[i]))
        }
    }
    print
}
$ 
$ gawk -f tst.awk file
91001440737;2015/01/19;2015/01/19;10;true;true;2015/01/20;;;;;;;;;
91001477235;2015/01/29;;3;true;true;;;;;;2015/02/01;;;2015/02/01;
91001512152;;2015/02/04;2;true;true;;;;;;2015/02/05;;;;
91001520460;2015/01/18;;13;true;true;2015/01/19;;;;2015/01/28;;;;;
91001627323;2015/01/31;;10;true;true;2015/02/02;;;;;;;;;
91001680088;2015/01/17;;2;true;true;;;2015/01/30;;;2015/01/18;;;;
```

The `split()` enumerates the fields that can contain timestamps.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton , I tried your line but it gives me error. For info, I'm on cygwin.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have this `}cat: tst.awk: No such file or directory
` It is like it is not recording anything.

Comment: I have to create the script. Fair enough. I will do.

Comment: I misunderstood the `cat` part. Sorry, still recovering from the flu. Bad excuse I know but I'm less agile. -_-